# Need to use protractor-sync module with cucumber

Tags: protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I am using [protractor-sync](https://github.com/blackboard/protractor-sync) module with cucumber so that to make the calls functions synchronously
But when I start using the functions of protractor-sync   **browserSync.get("https://www.google.com");**

**Error**

```
Error: Could not find the current asyncblock flow. Please make sure this method is called from an asyncblock
context.
```

**Error console:**

```
× Given Navigate to Google Page # Protractor\node_modules\cucumber\lib\support_code_library_builder\build_helpers.js:173
       Error: Could not find the current asyncblock flow. Please make sure this method is called from an asyncblock
context.
           at Object.exec (C:\Cucumber Protractor\node_modules\protractor-sync\dist\exec.js:10:19)
           at BrowserSync.get (C:\Cucumber Protractor\node_modules\protractor-sync\dist\browser-sync.js:34:23)
           at World.<anonymous> (C:\Cucumber Protractor\steps\LoginSteps.ts:12:15)
```

**Feature File**

```
Feature: Validation test

@CucumberScenario
Scenario: Validate Google Page
Given Navigate to Google Page
```

**Steps File:**

```
import { Given } from 'cucumber';
import { browserSync } from 'protractor-sync';

Given('Navigate to Google Page',{ timeout: 120 * 1000 }, ()=> {

  browserSync.get("https://www.google.com");

});
```

**protractor conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 240000,
  specs: [
    "./features/*.feature",
],
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"),
  cucumberOpts: {
    strict: true,
    compiler: 'ts:ts-node/register'

}

};
```

Can we use protractor-sync module along with cucumber
https://github.com/blackboard/protractor-sync

Comment: did you follow the guide from github page ?

Comment: Hey @infern0, i have checked the documentation of it protractor-sync , but my question is but any means tweaking it,  can we use it with cucumber , they implicitly mentioned about Jasmine